# Auto-Generated Emails Not Being Sent as HTML

Tags: html-email

In Admin > Email Configuration, I set “Default Mail Format” to “HTML”. Then I went to Design > Message Pages > Email Notifications and entered the following code into the “Member Account Activation Instructions” template:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>{site_name} Member Account Activation</title>

  <meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

  <style type="text/css">
   .list a {
    color: #cc0000; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    font-family: Verdana; 
    font-size: 11px; 
    text-decoration: none;
   }
   p {
    color: #3e3f3a; 
    font-family: Verdana; 
    font-size: 13px; 
    line-height: 20px;
   }
   h1 {
       color: #850d6f; 
       font-family: Verdana; 
       font-size: 16px; 
       font-weight:normal;
   }
   a:link, a:visited {
    color: #4a94ad;
   }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body marginheight="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" bgcolor="#fff" leftmargin="0">
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
   <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#850d6f" height="72">
     <img src="{site_url}/images/email/logo_03.png" width="121" height="40" alt="Logo 03">
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <h1>Thank you for your new member registration.</h1>

     <p>To activate your new account, please visit the following URL:</p>

     <p>{unwrap}{activation_url}{/unwrap}</p>

     </p>Thank You!</p>

     <p>--<a href="{site_url}">{site_name}</a></p>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>

  <!-- footer -->
  <table cellspacing="0" border="0" height="202" cellpadding="0" width="600">
   <tr>
    <td class="copyright" height="100" align="center" valign="top" width="600" colspan="2">
     <br>
    &copy; <a href="{site_url}">{site_url}</a><br>
     <a href="{site_url}contact-us">Contact Us</a> | <a href="{site_url}privacy-policy-and-terms-of-use">Privacy Policy and Terms of Use</a>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

But when I do a test member registration, the email received is in plain text (the HTML code is visible as text). The content-type of the email is “text/plain”.

HTML email sent via the Communication panel is sent correctly with a content-type of “multipart/alternative”.

HTML email sent with [MX Notify Control](http://www.eec.ms/add-ons/mx-notify-control) is also sent with the correct content-type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just had a quick look at the source code and my impression is that EE doesn't currently support HTML-formatted activation emails. Here's the relevant bit of the EE source:

```
$this->email->EE_initialize();
$this->email->wordwrap = TRUE;
$this->email->from($this->config->item('webmaster_email'), $this->config->item('webmaster_name'));  
$this->email->to($row['email']);
$this->email->subject($this->functions->var_swap($template['title'], $swap));   
$this->email->message(entities_to_ascii($this->functions->var_swap($template['data'], $swap)));     
$this->email->send();
```

In order to send out HTML-formatted messages the `mailtype` property has to be set. In this instance it isn't even referenced, so the default behaviour (plain text) is used.

Changing this should just be a matter of inserting the line below, however I wouldn't recommend doing so as you'd inevitably forget about it in an update and users would start to wonder why they're being sent raw HTML when they register.

```
$this->email->mailtype($this->config->item('mail_format'));
```

Since this would be a single-line code change you could always submit a feature request. That said, if this is something you need in a reasonable timescale an add-on is probably the way to go.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. What file does this code get added to?

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, specialty templates are not sent as html. maybe use something like http://madebyhippo.com/addons/view/libraree?

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Dom Stubbs' answer I created this extension to workaround this.

https://github.com/cld-agency/ee-html-email

Please note that if you are using any Freeform notifications, they will also need to be formatted with HTML, since this is a system-wide change.