# Email Displaying HTML Code

Tags: ee2, html-email

I am using EE's built-in Mailing List Activation Instructions email to send out an html templated email to users who signs up on the website's newsletter. The email is sending perfectly, but instead of displaying the rendered html template and content, it shows the html code directly onto the email client. Please see below.

[image: MS Outlook Displaying HTML Code]

It does the same with Gmail. I have set the default email type in the backend as HTML, but does not seem to take effect.

Is there perhaps anything I am missing or doing incorrectly maybe?

Answer (score 1):

EE's default system emails -- the ones that use Email Notification Templates -- are always sent as text. There's no code that allows them to be sent as HTML.

See: [Auto-Generated Emails Not Being Sent as HTML](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/497/auto-generated-emails-not-being-sent-as-html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the header (doctype) and footer? So start from

```
<table>
```

to the end of your main

`</table>`

and just that.

Comment: Can you take a moment to expand on this answer? I'd suggest adding where to make this edit in the control panel.

Comment: I see the comments have stripped out my table tag - grr